# Send email when a new user is created via iOS app using Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to send an email each time a new user is created in my iOS app. I'm using Parse.com as my back-end and have been reading about Cloud Code. I'm assuming I can use this to monitor object creation and kick off a function to send an email when a specific object (user) is created in the database. I know I can create a function within CloudCode then call this function in my iOS app once a user is created, but I'd like to be able to do this same thing without submitting an update to the App Store. Is there a way to accomplish this without submitting a new binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `afterSave` Cloud Code function then you don't need to change your app - the new code will simply be invoked every time your user object is saved.  This example uses SendGrid, so you would need a SendGrid account

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {

    if(!(request.object.existed())){
       var SendGrid = require("sendgrid");  
       SendGrid.initialize("username", "password");

       SendGrid.sendEmail({
          to: "email@example.com",
          from: "SendGrid@CloudCode.com",
          subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
          text: "Using Parse and SendGrid is great!"
        }, {
          success: function(httpResponse) {
             console.log(httpResponse);
          },
          error: function(httpResponse) {
             console.error(httpResponse);
          }
      });
    }
});
```